# The file is not a valid XML file. The file is not a valid XML document

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, infopath, infopath-2007

I am attempting to enter the url (http://servername:port#/_vti_bin/lists.asmx) of a web service for the Data Connection Wizard in InfoPath 2007 but I receive this error:

> The file is not a valid XML file.
>   The file is not a valid XML document.
>   A document must contain exactly one root element.
>   Line 1, Position 0

I have checked the url of the web service and it displays the list of operations.

Answer (score 0):

In the error dialog box there should be "show details" button. Provide the details more about the error.Please provide that details also.
Do you have any parameters to pass to this web service?If yes please verify the parameters.